# How to join a table with itself with two records per id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

So, I have a table with the following structure:

| id | columnA | columnB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |  |
| 1 |  | No |

I want to combine the row into a single row, so it ends up like this:

| id | columnA | columnB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | No |

I believe a self join here would work like this:

```
SELECT t1.columnA , t2.columnB 
FROM table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

But is there a way to do this without specifying the columns? I have a table that has 100 columns and I'm trying to see if I can accomplish this without listing out all the columns.

Comment: Postgres and Redshift are different databases.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Add some more sample data. Id's with just 1, or 3 different values, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query to get the column name with aggregation (Query created using information schema to get the column names). Write a select using the result and run the query.

```
select 
case when column_name='Id' then column_name
else concat(',Max(', column_name,')') end as Name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'Table1';
```

You will get something like below as output, where A and B are the column names.

```
Id
,Max(A)
,Max(B)
```

Add convert the result to query

```
Select 
Id
,Max(A)
,Max(B) 
from Table1 Group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do this without specifying the columns?

You can use `using` to answer your question.

```
SELECT t1.columnA , t2.columnB 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table1 t2
     USING (id);
```

To get the data you want, use aggregation:

```
SELECT id, MAX(t1.columnA), MAX(t2.columnB)
FROM table1 t1 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: What if I had several columns I wanted to keep? Do I have to specify all of them in my select statement?

Comment: you will have to mention all the columns so the SGBD doesn't get confused with identical names. you can get a simple query selecting the top 1000 rows of your table then you'll have all the names already written. Then you simply have to add T1 or T2 for whichever column you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

Use your JOIN only change the colums for *

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```